# Case When isnt returning data for the null

Tags: postgresql

I have a case statement that is not returning a null value. What am I missing in to get this to work.

```
Select CASE 
                WHEN transfer_sources.input_lot_type = 'Dried' THEN Sum(transfer_sources.weight)
                WHEN transfer_sources.input_lot_type = 'Fresh' THEN NULL
            END
        from transfer_sources join bulk_lots on transfer_sources.source_id = bulk_lots.id
        where transfer_sources.input_lot_type = 'Dried' and bulk_lots.name = 'BS190208-010'
        group by transfer_sources.input_lot_type
        LIMIT 1
```

I would like a null to show in the fresh column as i am trying to only calculate for dried

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove `WHERE` condition `transfer_sources.input_lot_type = 'Dried'`:

```
Select CASE 
            WHEN transfer_sources.input_lot_type = 'Dried' THEN Sum(transfer_sources.weight)
            WHEN transfer_sources.input_lot_type = 'Fresh' THEN NULL
        END
    from transfer_sources join bulk_lots on transfer_sources.source_id = bulk_lots.id
    where  bulk_lots.name = 'BS190208-010'
    group by transfer_sources.input_lot_type
```

Comment: If I remove the transfer_sources.input_lot_type = 'Dried' it places a null in all rows, I would like a null just in the fresh row and the actual amount in the dried row